# Python: split a float into different variables, add last float to first int and calculate

Tags: python, split, int

This is just for learning purpose. I want to do the following.

```
x = 5.0
y = 888.0
z= y / x
print z # 177.6
...?
```

Now I want to change the last part of the float to int and add the last number of the float (.6) as 6 to the first number (to get 777 from 177.6). After that I want to add the difference of 777 and y to a new variable to get 888 back.

Would be great if someone can explain how to do that! :)
edit: possible solution in the last code of this post.

The purpose of this is to understand how to perform such tasks in python and to get a better understanding of something I would call "mathematic symmetry".

You can find this symmetry while performing calculations like:

```
666 / 5.0 #133.2
777 / 5.0 #155.4
888 / 5.0 #177.6
999 / 5.0 #199.8
666.6 / 5.0 #133.32
```

I'm not an academic, so maybe this sounds mad. It is just a part of a theory in my spaghetti monster mind and with a script I could further investigate what this is about. ;)

With the help of the comments i was able to create this code. I'm quite sure it looks ugly from a professional programmers view, but hey, it's one of my first steps and im very happy with that! Thank you again! :)

```
x = 5.0
y = 888.0
z= y / x
print z # 177.6
print
a = int(str(z)[0])
print "First Number = " + str(a)
print
b = int(str(z)[1])
c = int(str(z)[2])
print "In between = " + str(b) + str(c)
d = int(str(z)[-1]) # treat z as string, take first string after . from z and format it back to int
print "Last Number = " + str(d)
print
res = str(a+d) +str(b) +str(c)
to_int = int(res)
dif = y - to_int
add = to_int + dif
print add
```

Edit: Is there some magic happening in this code? The actual code seems to be inteded to calculate numbers like 777.7 But when i run it with y = 7277.7727 it gives the correct output even if i only have 2 digits in between? I was expecting wrong calculations. o0

Edit: Resolved. A logical failure in the calculations created the unexpected result. Practically i was printing y at the end. xD

Comment: This can be achieved by a mixture of text-based operations and numeric operations. Note that 177.6 can't be represented precisely, you only get a number close to it due to the binary representation with limited range.

Comment: Do you only care about the first decimal place when adding onto y?

Comment: If i try 777,777 / 5 = 155,5554 i would say no, because in that case it would be the last one. Like in the example with 666.6
Thank you for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the safest way is using string manipulation:

```
int(str(177.123)[-1])
3

int(str(177.123).split('.')[-1])
123
```

But I am afraid you'll be eventually bitten by floating point precision issues. A package for symbolic math like sympy might be more suitable for your purpose than standard floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you Goyo! That helps me to get the right direction. :)

Comment: I try to summarize what i learned from that. The first code treats z as string, takes the last string from z and format it back to int. Is this correct? I think (hope!) now i understand python a bit better. This language is really cool! :)

Is .split called an argument? So i could also say x.split(':') if x is formatted like a string time value?

Comment: @Horst23 "takes the last string from z" is the last character. `.split()` is called a method and I guess you are right about `x.split(':')` but you'd better try in the python interpreter and know for sure.